# How to make Cohort User Retention analysis from User Login Data in Tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, visualization

I have this data which contain two tables:

**User Table**

- UserID
- DateOfJoining

**Events Table**

- EventID
- UserID
- AnonymousID
- EventName
- EventRequestedOn
- RequestUserAgent
- RequestURL

I'm kind of new to Tableau. I'm not understanding what filters to apply to get a cohort retention analysis like the one below. Could you help me with this.

[image]

I explored around the filters and came up with the visualization below, but the data doesn't seem to be right to me. **Could you tell me what is going wrong.** The use case is to prepare a visualization so that I can understand how to retain users in what areas for which events.

[image]

Comment: In your data extract fields there is date field `Timestamp` what is that? Have you joined both tables? where is events data?

Comment: Timestamp is the date when an user performs any action, an event on application. I've joined both tables to get Date Of Joining of the user and his events on website.

Comment: please give me some sample data to work on.  Better upload it on drive and share the link.